# Core Data saves data into the wrong database at first start

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have an DataModel with two configurations. One for preload data and the another one for user data.
On first start the preload SQLLite Database is copied to the Documents Folder. The user data Database is created by Core Data in the ApplicationSupport Directory. Everything works fine so far. But now the problem: If it is the first start, nothing is saved, even though the saveContext() Method has been called. All user data are gone at the next app start. But it is not the first start, everything works fine and all user data is there at the next app start. Has anyone any idea what the problem is? Here my Core Data Stack:

```
    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "CoreData_App")

        container.persistentStoreDescriptions[0].configuration = "PreloadData"
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions[0].url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("PreloadData.sqlite")

        let userStoreDescription = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("UserData.sqlite"))
        userStoreDescription.configuration = "UserData"

        container.persistentStoreDescriptions.append(userStoreDescription)


        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support

    func saveContext () {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**
After a lot of tests, I have found that data are stored in the preload database at the first start and at the second start correctly in the user data database. But I want to save the data also at the first start in the user database. Here the code where I save the data:

```js
@IBAction func pressedFavoriteButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if userRating == nil {
            let rating = UserRating(context: DataController.sharedInstance.persistentContainer.viewContext)
            rating.entryID = (entry?.id)!
            userRating = rating
        }

        apiHandler.sendRequest(.POST) { (response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.userRating?.isFavorite = !self.favoriteButton.isSelected
                self.favoriteButton.isSelected = !self.favoriteButton.isSelected
                
               DataController.sharedInstance.saveContext()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You must be initializing Core Data stack improperly. Please share your code.

Comment: I have no idea where the problem is, so its hard to know what I should share. But i have add the Code of my Core Data Stack to the question now.

Comment: Which version of Swift was used in your project?

Comment: It uses Swift 3

Comment: Are you recursively saving it to the database?

Comment: Does the userRating belong to Preload or User Configuration?

Comment: It belongs to User Configuration

Answer (score 0):

First let's setup the stores correctly,

```
let preloadDataStoreDescription = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("PreloadData.sqlite"))

let userStoreDescription = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("UserData.sqlite"))

    userStoreDescription.configuration = "UserData"
preloadDataStoreDescription.configuration = "PreloadData"

container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [preloadDataStoreDescription, userStoreDescription]
```

Since you have 2 databases, it depends on what entity you are storing.

If the entity belongs to the Preload configuration it will be stored in preload database, else it will be stored in user database.

P.S.
You can also debug further using the flag

```
-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1
```

in Edit Scheme > Arguments > Arguments Passed on launch

Also, I would suggest to not complicate the design with 2 databases, if not really required.

Comment: Thanks for the better setup code. Yes, i know how works configurations, but the problem is it stored ALL data in the preload database (also the entities which are not in the preload Configuration) at the first start. After the first start everything works.

Comment: I have tried looking at your question and the details that you gave. It should behave in the way you described. Trying to store an entity in the database that it doesn't belong to should lead to an exception.